# JQuery Animations Messy

Tags: jquery, animation, hover

So I'm trying to code this navigation and have got it all working except that sometimes the JQuery animation either breaks or is jumpy if you move your mouse too quickly. In Safari it looks pretty dreadful as well, it seems to almost flash the animations?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // On hover:
    $('#navigation li').hoverIntent(function () {
        width = $(this).children('span:nth-child(2)').width();
        text = $(this).children('span:nth-child(2)');          

        var newwidth = (width + 15) // Original width + 15px padding        
        text.animate({"width":"0px"}, 0).show(); // Make the width 0px and make the element visible
        text.animate({"width":+newwidth+"px"}, 300); // Animate the width to the new size

    },
    function () {
        text.animate({"width":"0px"}, 300); // Animate the width to 0px and hide the element
        text.animate({"width":+width+"px","float":"left"}, 0);
        setTimeout(function() {
            text.hide();
        }, 300);
    });

});
```

Here's a JFiddle of it:

http://jsfiddle.net/d8g4w/

Also, live preview so you can see what it actually looks like:

http://dev.evaske.com/Navigation/

Answer (score 0):

See what this does for you: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brianflanagan/6RU9u/)

Right off the bat, I noticed that the markup wasn't 100% valid (anchor tags as immediate children of the `ul` node) and animating the 'float' property felt a bit weird to me (I'm not even sure jQuery supports animation of 'float').  I stripped out some of the cross-browser CSS declarations (that didn't seem to have any bearing on the animation).  You don't really need the anchor tags since you were handling the cursor with the CSS and the hover with a combination of CSS and JS.  If you need to trigger from a mouseclick (which, if this is a navigation, I'm sure you will) I recommend using:

`$('#navigation li').on('click', function(){...}`

I tend to avoid using .hover() and instead rely more on

`.on('mouseenter', function(){...})` 
and 
`.on('mouseleave', function(){...})`

as they more accurately represent the actual events I'm usually trying to target.

Probably the biggest improvement came from injecting the `.stop()` method before the `.animate()`.  This seemed to instantly reduce the jittering that I was experiencing.  FF is still definitely the weakest as far as smoothness is concerned (I didn't even bother trying IE because you mentioned Safari and FF) but I wasn't seeing the hiccuping any longer.

Comment: Is there a way to stop it from if the person hovers over it and then quickly hovers over it many times the text flashes in and out.

Comment: Probably.  :)  Is this the kind of interaction behavior you expects users to engage in?